# How do I get to Måskåsj-gammen?

Tags: huts, sweden

In 2013 I visited Nuortakrågge:

[image: Nuortakrågge]

Nuortakrågge is located at 67.8084°N, 16.6203°E, above Vuodnabahta, Norway.  It is open and free to use.  It is not listed on official maps but there is a small sign along the main trail from Vuodnabahta to the Swedish border.

Some entries in the visitor book mentioned Maskåsj-gammen on the Swedish side of the border.  Måskåsj-gammen is not on any maps either, and there is no sign pointing there along the trail from the border to Vásjáluokta.  I asked local Sami people on the boat from Vuodnabahta to Ájluokta, who gave me a description that wasn't very useful (something like "turn left a bit after the 5th stream crossing, but there is no trail"), and pointed out that all the names on the map are wrong (and they don't use the maps because they know the way).

I found [a blogpost with a photo](http://krigsminner.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/maskasjgammen-et-samisk-kulturminne-med.html):

[image: Måskåsj-gammen]
*Måskåsj-gammen.  Photo by Oddmund Andersen.  Source: [krigsminner blog](http://krigsminner.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/maskasjgammen-et-samisk-kulturminne-med.html)*

The blog says it is "roughly 6 km into Sweden", which in the local landscape is not precise enough to find it, in particular since there is apparently no trail leading there.  I don't think it would be possible to find on Google Earth.  There is a map [in this document about the history of WW II refugees](http://img7.custompublish.com/getfile.php/3211209.927.wexeyqyyrr/Vandreutstillingen_liten_NY.pdf) but the scale is far too poor to locate the spot in the landscape.

What are the geographic coordinates for Måskåsj-gammen, or where is it relative to locations as written on the official topographic map (regardless of the correctness of the names on them)?

Comment: It is called "Rautokåtan" in Swedish if this can help.

Comment: Hi gerrit! Did you ever take the trip to this pretty place, or at least get the information you needed? Can you provide us with an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Ondska No, Rautojaurestugan is a different cabin completely, operated by STF, located on the map, and located right along the trail.

Comment: @Sue Not yet. I originally asked this on a Swedish forum back in 2013 but no-one ever replied. I'm quite sure the locals who built the Nuortakrågge would know but they don't really have an online presence and I'm too shy to phone a stranger out of the blue and communicate in a Norwegian language foreign to both of us, and I doubt they could tell me the GPS-coordinates anyway; they just "know the way" after all!

Comment: @gerrit Not sure that Rautojaurestugan is the same as Rautokåtan. Anyway that was the info I had found in your link to krigsminner blog.

Comment: @Ondska Sorry, maybe you're right and some people use Rautojaure for Måskåsj-gammen; in any case, [this is what the STF shelter called Rautojaure looks like](https://roversmountains.files.wordpress.com/2016/12/dscn0016.jpg).

Comment: Thanks for responding! I'm too shy to call strangers out of the blue like that too! I just happened to find this in the Unanswered Questions list, and was hoping it could be answered and brought forward so people could see.

Comment: @Sue I may try again next time I'm in the area.  Maybe in 2020.